# ColorMixer Screenshots

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Does anyone have screenshots of Commonware's [ColorMixer](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) widget? I am specifically considering using the ColorMixerDialog, but want to know how it looks before I go forward with using it over other color pickers.

Comment: Download, install, and run the demo app. It's three `SeekBar` widgets (red, green, blue) and a square `View` for a color swatch (showing the color obtained from mixing those three R/G/B values).